# Converting panda's dataframe group iteration into groupby with apply

Tags: python, pandas

I need to split a dataframe into groups, and for those groups that have odd number of lines, i need to pull in the first line whose column matches a certain condition and then i need to assemble back all such first lines (so only the first ones in odd numbered groups matching a condition). I can do it in a loop like below (it works) but can't rework it into a groupby with apply. Could you help?

```
grp_by_cols=['A','B']
new_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=grp_by_cols)
for name, group in txn.groupby(grp_by_cols):
if len(group) % 2 != 0:
    new_df=new_df.append(group[group['C']=='something')].head(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem which I would solve by writing a function which you then pass to apply.

Suppose you had data like this (would have been handy with the question):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

DF = pd.DataFrame({
        'key'   : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7],
        'data1' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C',
                 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
        'data2' : [random.random() for x in xrange(18)]})
```

Where key is the column you will group on, and 'data1' is the column you will use to test the condition. This data have odd numbers of observations for groups 1, 3, 5, and 7. The 'data1' values for those groups at the first observation are 'A', 'B', A', 'B'. Suppose for example you wanted to get a new dataframe with the first observations in those groups, but only where the 'data1' value in that first row is equal to B. We could write a general function like this:

```
def apply_func(df, col, condition):
    if len(df)%2 == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if df.irow(0)[col] == condition:
            return df.irow(0)
        else:
            return None
```

and then call it on the groups as follows:

```
DF.groupby('key').apply(apply_func, 'data1', 'B').dropna()
```

which gives the following output:

```
  data1     data2  key
2     B  0.980814    3
6     B  0.428402    7
```

Which if I am not mistaken is the type of output you want to generate.

Of course you dont actually need all those branches in the function, I include them just to make it clearer. The most concise way to write the function is:

```
def apply_func(df, col, condition):
    if len(df)%2 != 0 and df.irow(0)[col] == condition:
        return df.irow(0)
```

Note that when calling passing a function to apply, the fist argument passed is the DataFrame itself and this is done so automatically. That is why you don't need to specify the 'df' argument when passing the function to apply. In fact if you do you get an error saying you have passed too many arguments. Also somewhat strangely in my view when passing the function the arguments are supplied after commas rather than in parenthese. This I find confusing to look at, but it is what it is....

Comment: Canonical! Thank you Sir